# Flutter: How can I make ClipRRect to display image instead of transparent color?

Tags: flutter

I want to have a bottomAppBar with border radius.

When bottomAppBar is hovering image. ClipRRect should display image instead of transparent color.

[image: bottomAppBar]

Here is the code:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(            
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(...),             
        ],
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(             
        
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: BottomAppBar(child:Stack(...))
```

How can I make ClipRRect to display image instead of transparent color ?

Comment: You would have to use a stack widget and use borderRadius for Container. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8&vl=en